# Firefox OS: Detect and Override Volume Control Rocker

Tags: web-applications, volume, firefox-os

Is it possible to detect and override the volume control rocker in the Firefox OS? Such as catching a event and being able to handle it for the purpose of my app.

Answer (score 0):

Not at the moment. It's coming for version 2.1 of Firefox OS, see the tracking bug here: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=989198